# .Net desktop program suddenly starts erroring out

Tags: .net, configuration

A long time ago I wrote a little FTP utility for a client, and it has been working just fine for over a year.  The other day, they tell me that they "updated" their machines (including the server where this was installed).  Suddenly, my tiny little desktop app started erroring out.  Here is the error message:

The configuration section 'connectionStrings' has an unexpected declaration

Which is interesting because my app doesn't even HAVE a connectionStrings entry in the config file.

I do use a 3rd party dll, but from the stacktrace, it appears that it is blowing up when trying to access a property that I made in my own Settings.settings file -- the property is called FTPserver, and not anything to do with my 3rd party dll, PowerTCP.

Anyone have any ideas where I can start diagnosing the real issue?

EDIT (added a screenshot, then removed it because it didn't help anything)

![alt text][1]

EDIT2:  Damn Image Shack.  Here it is typed out:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The configuration section 'connectionStrings' has an unexpected declaration.
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManger.get_ConnectionStrings()
at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.get_ConnectionStrings()
at System.Configuration.LocatFileSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext contect, SettingsPropertyCollection properties)
at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(SettingsProvider provider)
at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String propertyName)
at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
at FTPAndArchive.Properties.Settings.get_FTPserver() in 
        <a path to my local machine...which it isn't even running on?>.Settings.Designer.cs: line 43
at FTPAndArchive.FtpAndArchive..ctor() in <my path again>FtpAndAchive.cs: line 25
at FTPAndArchive.Program.Main() in <again>.Program.cs: line 21
```

Comment: Did you catch the complete exception? If yes, please post them.

Comment: $#@^$* ImageShack does a great job of making big images completely unreadable.

Comment: I just realized that, I'm sorry.  I typed it all out (I'm sure I have typos) and edited my question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I told my client to try something as a complete stab in the dark, and they said that all is fine now.

They went into the permissions on the folder in question, and added ASPNET as a user, and propagated those permissions down.  Now they say that it works.

I don't really like that solution.  But they are happy because it is up and running now.

If anyone has any concrete solution and evidence that it would work, too, I'll accept their answer instead of my own.

Thanks MrMarco and MusiGenesis for your time.  I hope you don't feel that I've wasted it.

Comment: That's weird - I thought you said this was a desktop app.

Comment: I did, and that is why I said it would be a huge shot in the dark to my client.  And also why I'm not really sure WHY it even worked.  It is 100% a desktop app.

Even more confused now...

Comment: My guess is that they accidentally granted and propagated permissions to Everyone while adding user ASPNET.  I can't think of any other reason why ASPNET would have anything to do with a desktop app. I dunno.

Comment: Good point.  So, merely resetting permissions and having them propagate down would have done it, the ASPNET user was just a red herring.  Thanks!

Comment: In my case, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config was missing on the server. Copied the machine.config from another server and its resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using FtpWebRequest or WebClient in your app?  You might be running into a proxy server problem.

Comment: Nope.  I'm not personally doing anything web related, only instantiating and calling some methods through PowerTCP.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. But got some correlation between the connection and the configuration file. Normally SQLEXPRESS gets installed along with VS. and our Machine.Config file has a connection string section:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I assume something is wrong in the Machine.Config file. The new installation might have updated the same.